What time window to use for independent variables?
I have 10000 listings on various days. My y variable is % of transactions that happened 7 days before listing with a loss > 0 is 30% or more then 1 else 0. Now losses can happen before listing also. When I take x variables for decision tree which are before listing, it can overlap with the loss date. Is this acceptable?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
